# What were the two stones at Pi HaChiros?

Tags: beshalach

The Mechilta D'Rebbi Yishmael (14:2) [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d%27Rabbi_Yishmael.14.2.2?lang=bi&with=Midrash&lang2=en)

> וישובו ויחנו לפני פי החירות, מה היו חירות הללו לא היו משופעות אלא
> גדודיות ולא היו תרוטות אלא מוקפות ולא היו עגולות אלא מרובעות ולא היו
> מעשה אדם אלא מעשה שמים ועינים היו להם לפותחות כמין זכר וכמין נקיבה היו
> דברי ר' אליעזר - "they returned and encamped before Pi Hachiros":
> What were these "chiros"? (Two rocks, which were) not slanting, but
> straight; not open (between them), but surrounded (by stones, not
> affording passage between them); not round, but square; not man-made,
> but Heaven-made; with (the figure of) open eyes; one (in the figure
> of) a male, and (the other in the figure of) a female. These are the
> words of R. Eliezer.

Are there any sources which discuss these two square, Heavenly stones at Pi Hachiros? Their description seems eerily similar to the Luchos...

Comment: Consider the letter Chet in K’tav Ashurit according to the teaching of the Ari z”l, engraved in stone (perhaps naturally occurring). According to Sefer Yetzirah, the letters are called stones. It is comprised form-wise of a Vav and a Zayin which fulfill the rest of the description. Those two forms are joined to form the single letter. The numerical value of the parts, 6&7, is 13, אח״ד. The Chet has the form of a gate, like an opening, as in פי, פה. The Vav and Zayin aspects also allude to male and female in a state of union.

Answer (score 1):

They are also discussed in the [Targum Yonasan](https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jonathan_on_Exodus.14?lang=bi) to the verse:

> מַלֵיל עִם בְּנֵי יִשְרָאֵל וִיתוּבוּן לַאֲחוֹרֵיהוֹן וְיִשְׁרוּן קֳדָם פּוּמֵי חִירָתָא מַרְבִּיעָתָא דְאִתְבְּרִיוּ בְּגַוְונֵי בְּנֵי נְשָׁא דְכַר וְנוּקְבָא וְעַיְינִין פְּתִיחַן לְהוֹן הוּא אַתְרָא דְטָנֵיס דְּבֵינֵי מִגְדוֹל וּבֵינֵי יַמָּא קֳדָם טַעֲוַת צְפוֹן דְּמִשְׁתַּיֵּיר מִכָּל טַעֲוָון דְּמִצְרָיִם בְּגִין דְּיֵמְרוּן מִצְרָאֵי בָּחִיר הוּא בַּעַל צְפוֹן מִכָּל טַעֲוָותָא דְאִשְׁתַּיֵּיר וְלָא לָקָא דְיֵיתוּן לְמִסְגוֹד לֵיהּ וְיִשְׁכְּחוּן יַתְכוֹן דְּאַתּוּן שְׁרָן לְקִבְלֵיהּ עַל גֵּיף יַמָּא
> Speak to the sons of Israel, that they return back, and encamp before the Mouths of Hiratha, as they lie, created after the manner (likeness) of the children of men, male and female, and their eyes open to them: it is the place of Tanes, which is between Migdol and the sea, before the idol Zephon (Typhon), that is left of all the idols of Mizraim. For the Mizraee will say, More excellent is Baal Zephon than all idols, because it is left, and not smitten; and therefore will they come to worship it, and will find that you are encamped nigh unto it, on the border of the sea.